# Files are hidden after reinstalling OS X

Tags: macos

I have an imac which is about 5 or 6 years old. I had been running Leopard on it but my iphoto quit working so I reinstalled the OS X that came with the computer. Although it shows 366 GB are used on my hard drive I can't see any files. How do I restore my computer to where it was? Time machine shows no back up.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to open your hard drive (not your user home folder).

In that window you should see all users on your computer. The one with home icon is the main user folder.

Also you could run this in terminal to unhide the folders/files

```
sudo chflags nohidden /Users
```